# How to make SQL Server Agent job write to a file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, file-io

I need to deliver a stored procedure to a client, who will set up a scheduled job to output to a file. The client thinks the stored procedure should write to the file, but I'm surprised that I can't just produce a table and ask their DB admin to set up the job so the output goes to a file.

The file has to conform to a specific format for import into another system.

I have a query SELECT (code for header) UNION ALL SELECT (code that creates a string for each entry) UNION ALL SELECT (code for footer).

The expression is rather complicated, and I don't want to cram it all into a BCP string argument.

What is the best way to do this? Can BCP call a stored procedure? Can the SQL Job description "redirect" output to a file? Should I create a temp table and point BCP at that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have bcp exec a stored proc and have the results put into a table.

Please see this question that seems to do what you want:

[using BCP to export stored procedure result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095355/using-bcp-to-export-stored-procedure-result-in-sql-server-2008)