# Writing the result set of a stored procedure directly int a textfile from within the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I want to use a stored procedure to write out the summary of a an income table into a text file.

I have created a stored procedure that takes two integer arguments (month and year) and print out the result on SSMS. I don't want to go through the manual option of exporting result to text. Below is the structure of the stored procedure (I am using adventureworks database here as an illustration, but my stored procedure is exactly of the same structure):

```
create proc monthlySummary(@month int, @year int) as
begin
    set nocount on
    declare
    @monthSTR nvarchar(2), @yearSTR nvarchar(4), @selectList nvarchar(200)
    set @monthSTR = CONVERT(nvarchar(2),@month)
    set @yearSTR = CONVERT (nvarchar(4), @year)
    set @selectList = 'SELECT*FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ModifiedDate)= '
    +@monthSTR + 'AND '+ 'DATEPART(YEAR, ModifiedDate)='+@yearSTR
    

    EXEC sp_executesql @selectList
end
```

I want the result to be written out directly on a text file instead of being displayed on SSMS.

Comment: Have you tried the "Results To File" option? (Ctrl-Shift-F)

Comment: It's a little tricky for an internal SQL Process to gain access to the external world to create a file. Usually this is done the other way - an external process sucks the data out. IF you really want to push it out, here are a couple of links, but be aware `xp_cmdshell` is generally disabled and frowned upon. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095355/using-bcp-to-export-stored-procedure-result-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Arg. Do NOT convert to string to construct your dates. It's slower (often a LOT slower), more code, and more error prone. [DateTimeFromParts()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is your friend.

Comment: i converted to string because i use the sp_executsql function in the stored procedure as this uses already created execution plan instead of having to recreate the execution plan over again for each subsequent call of the procedure.

Comment: Yes i have done result to file and it worked perfectly.  However i am looking for a way to make my procedure do that implicitly.

Comment: What @JoelCoehoorn means is this type of code is stupid `DATEPART(MONTH, ModifiedDate)= '
    +@monthSTR + 'AND '+ 'DATEPART(YEAR, ModifiedDate)='+@yearSTR` because it prevents SQL Server from using indexes and any other optimisation that may exist. What it should be instead is this `ModifiedDate >= DATEFROMPARTS ( @yearSTR, @monthSTR, 1 ) AND  ModifiedDate < DATEADD( month, 1,  DATEFROMPARTS ( @yearSTR, @monthSTR, 1 )) `. Never wrap the searched column in a function if you want good performance.

Comment: "
i converted to string because i use the sp_executsql function in the stored procedure as this uses already created execution plan" - this make no sense. You are concatenating strings to construct your query. A new execution plan will be created for each set of parameters as you are executing a new query. To void this you actually need to pass parameters to `sp_executesql ` . All of this is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: check out bcp utility, it can select the stuff you need, but calling external programs from code directly means you need to enable xp_cmdshell

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use SQLCMD as in the following:

```
SQLCMD -S server -d database -E -Q "EXEC dbo.monthlySummary" -o out.txt
```

It connects to the server, executes the query and creates the txt file. File formats (header, column separator,.. ) can be customized with command line switches -w -h -s.

hope this helps.